# Laminated floor dilaminated

Tags: laminate-floor, laminate

My laminated floor has slightly delaminated.

I have two questions:

1. Is this actually laminated floor?
2. Can I use glue to glue that part down again? I tried taping it down, and it works fine but it's visible. The tape is visible. Do you think I can use clear superglue instead to glue it back to the bottom layer?

[image]
Thanks

Comment: The reason for the delamination is probably more important to know.  A water leak could a first guess.  Imagine glue would fix it if weight was left on top  to hold it down, if the rest of the board is in good condition for the glue to hold on to.

Comment: Please try again with the photo and get the critical area in focus. What's the product? Is it wood or synthetic material? Neither question can be answered without more information.

Comment: Yes, need a better-focused pic.  Maybe place an object adjacent to the delamination so the camera can focus on that?